# Changing focus from one text field to the next in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two `textFormField` widgets.  Once the user has completed the first text field I would like to focus on the next `textField`.  Is there a way to do this in Flutter?  Currently, the done button just closes the keyboard.  I was guessing the `focusNode` class might be the answer to this but not really sure how that works does anyone have any good examples of focusNode class? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, [FocusNode](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html)  and the `onFieldSubmitted` from a [TextFormField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) are probably the way to go.

> FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);

Here is an example that may help:

```
    FocusNode textSecondFocusNode = new FocusNode();

    TextFormField textFirst = new TextFormField(
      onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(textSecondFocusNode);
      },
    );

    TextFormField textSecond = new TextFormField(
      focusNode: textSecondFocusNode,
    );

    // render textFirst and textSecond where you want
```

You may also want to trigger `FocusScope.of()` from a button rather than onFieldSubmitted, but hopefully the above example gives you enough context to construct an appropriate solution for your use case.

Comment: how to change the button on the keyboard in this case? from checkmark to arrow like other apps have

Comment: @busuu From what I understand, this will not change the button on the keyboard.  It will just change the behavior of the `enter` key on the keyboard so that it will change focus to the next field.  It's the best we got for now.

Comment: @busuu In order to change the check button on the keyboard to an arrow, set the following on your TextFormField.    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next

Comment: in case you need add more actions to the keyboard, take a look a this package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_actions

Comment: useful for OTP authentication.

Comment: In the Android Simulator anyone know how to make the PC/Mac Tab key go to the next field to speed up human testing?

Answer (score 38):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**No need to use `FocusNode`**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'First Name'),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Last Name'),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          onSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: its is worked for me well is there is any way to focus previous one when tap erase/delete on text input screen

Comment: @A.K.J.94 You can use `onChanged` property and handle your logic in it.

Comment: but if the next texfield has a prefixIcon, it would not get focus, what to do about that?

Answer (score 9):

There's a similar method like in Android.

Add

```
textInputAction
```

parameter to the TextFormField  Widget, then add the property as;

```
 TextInputAction.next
```

Comment: Doesn't this only change the pop-up keyboard?

Comment: This actually works but only if the text field has no suffix widget with onPressed set

Comment: @Ammar Mohammad have you find the solution..?

Answer (score 8):

This is how I did it:

```
  var _focusNodes = List.generate(6, (index) => FocusNode()));
```

And in the TextFormField:

```
  TextFormField(
    focusNode: _focusNodes[i],
    maxLines: 1,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    onChanged: (text) {
      if (i < _controllers.length) {
        if (text.isEmpty)
          _focusNodes[i - 1].requestFocus();
        else
          _focusNodes[i + 1].requestFocus();
      }
    },
  ),
```